# Pydub library to find the loudest portion of an audio clip, save from 5 seconds before to 5 seconds after, and print out the max decibels?

Tags: python, audio, pydub, m4a, decibel

I want to take m4a files from iPhones and use Python to find the max-decibel portion of the segment. I then want to trim the clip to start 5 seconds before, and end 5 seconds after the max-decibel point. Lastly, I want it to print out the decibel level.

I figure the pydub library will be beneficial in this task. I am not looking for code, but to be pointed in the right direction of how I should approach this.

I have added the pydub library:

`from pydub import AudioSegment audio = AudioSegment.from_file('file.m4a')`